# Helm concatenated strings not being rendered

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm working in a Chart template for managing deployments for different microservices apps.

On the values file the container Apps are declared in a list, as you can see:

```
# values.yaml
containerApps:
  - name: app1
    replicaCount: 1
    ...
  - name: app2
    replicaCount: 1
    ...
  - name: app3
    replicaCount: 1
    ...
```

The template reads the values-file definition in a loop that outputs the K8S YAML file.

```
{{- range $containerApp := .Values.containerApps }}
{{- with $containerApp }}
...
      containers:
        - name: {{ .name }}
          image: "{{ printf "$.Values.%s.image_repository" .name }}:{{ printf "$.Values.%s.image_tag" .name }}"
          replicas: {{ .replicaCount }}
          ...
...
```

Besides the values-file, we have also some values being declared using imperative approach via `--set-string` parameter.

```
helm template . --name-template my-app --namespace dev \
--set-string app1.image_repository=my-registry/image-app-1 \
--set-string app1.image_tag=073f799 \
--set-string app2.image_repository=my-registry/image-app-2 \
--set-string app2.image_tag=934df33 \
--set-string app3.image_repository=my-registry/image-app-3 \
--set-string app3.image_tag=k393caf... \
--values values.yaml
```

The problem is that helm doesn't seem to be able to render the template interpreting the `$.Values.%s.image_repository" .name`, generating a wrong output:

```
# What we expected:
image: my-registry/image-app-1:073f799
...
image: my-registry/image-app-2:934df33
...
image: my-registry/image-app-3:k393caf
...

# What we get...
...
image: $.Values.app1.image_repository:$.Values.app1.image_tag
...
image: $.Values.app2.image_repository:$.Values.app2.image_tag
...
image: $.Values.app3.image_repository:$.Values.app3.image_tag
...
```

We understand that maybe `printf` is not the way to go, and I've tried also `index`, which haven't work as well.

If you someone can give us a clue on how to get this working, it would be really appreciated.

Any idea is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observe, `printf` will produce a string but not evaluate it, which is why you're getting the template expressions directly in your output.

I would in fact use `index` here.  I probably would do this by looking up the top-level value once, and then indexing within that.

```yaml
{{- range .Values.containerApps }}
{{- $image := index $.Values .name }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .name }}
          image: "{{ $image.image_repository }}:{{ $image.image_tag }}"
          replicas: {{ .replicaCount }}
{{- end }}
```

`range` already resets the special variable `.` to the list item, so you do not need the inner `with` (unless you expect the list items to potentially be empty).  I set `$image` to the top-level item from `.Values`, and then when you need to use it, you can reference fields in it like `$image.image_tag`.

Comment: Hi @david-maze thanks for the valuable input.

I have applied the suggested change but the image is being printed like this:

```
image: :
...
image: :
...
image: :
...
``` 

How can we output the $image.image_repository variable?

Comment: The syntax I show should work.  In particular, if you're not getting an error referencing `$image.image_repository` then the `index` call is finding something in the top-level `.Values`.

Comment: It seems that the `$image.image_repository` is returning a null value. There's no error at all though.

Comment: You could try emitting `# {{ toJson $image }}` as a YAML comment just to see what its value is.

Comment: Adding the comment returns `null`

Comment: Hi @david-make, my apologies. It was my fault... there was a mismatch in the imperative variables. Now it's working perfectly.

Thank you so much. You are my hero!!! :)